# Need help building libpandoc, Haskell + C and .NET bindings for Pandoc

Tags: c, haskell, pandoc

I'd love to use Pandoc in a utility I'm writing (C# console app) and I found this bindings project on GitHub, [libpandoc](https://github.com/toyvo/libpandoc) and by extension, it's .NET bindings project, [libpandoc-dotnet](http://github.com/toyvo/libpandoc-dotnet/).

I wish the author had included the built DLL but I suppose he wanted to leave it open to future Pandoc versions.

**I have no Haskell experience whatsoever**, I just want the .NET bindings in the end. I'm trying to install the dependencies via `cabal` but I don't understand the error messages and a cursory search leads me to believe installing `base` is a no-no, so I'm not sure what to do.

`C:\Development\Contrib\libpandoc>cabal install base-4.1.0.0
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: base (user goal)
rejecting: base-3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1, 4.6.0.1, 4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0/installed-7c8...,
4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1,
4.2.0.0 (global constraint requires ==4.1.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.1.0.0 (only already installed instances can be used)
rejecting: base-4.0.0.0 (global constraint requires ==4.1.0.0)`

If a kind soul could even *build the damn thing* (fork it? upload it somewhere?) I'd love you forever. Alternatively, show me how to build it properly and I can handle it from there I think. Though now that I think about it, not sure I have a C compiler installed.

**Update:**

OK. So it all comes down to the fact that libpandoc is 3 years old and its dependencies are out of date. I had no luck trying to get all the old Haskell tools to install and work, I probably had no idea what I was doing. I got as far as installing some dependencies but some dependencies weren't versioned so I had to track each version specifically and I eventually gave up.

I then just updated the dependency versions *for libpandoc* itself and now I've got all the dependencies built and linked.

The only remaining issue is that libpandoc needs to be updated to work against the latest Pandoc release (1.10).

Comment: What version of `cabal` are you using? Is it from the Haskell Platform?

Comment: Yes, whatever the latest version is. I updated the `base` version dependency in `libpandoc.cabal` and it now finds all the dependencies but I'm getting build errors (perhaps old version incompatibility). I'm running `cabal` and `runhaskell` through Command Prompt (Windows 7 x64).

Comment: I think the author, [@toyvo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/386685/toyvo), is hanging on SO (particularly F# tag). Hope he'll see this question.

Comment: I seem to be making progress. If it works out, I'll add answer. **edit**: YES. I've finally got it to actually build `LibPandoc` but now of course with 3-year-old code, it's out of date and the bindings need to be fixed, so everything builds but LibPandoc does not.

Comment: @subkamran have you considered just calling the pandoc executable directly? Its [command line interface](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) is flexible and well-documented.

Comment: Yup, I ended up just doing that. #igiveup :)

Comment: Did you ever get this working with latest Pandoc, and if so can you upload it somewhere?